# Making JS Functions Follow a STRICT Order (aka, I Still Don't Get Promises)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

First, let me lay out what I want to do, in the simplest terms:

**I have a series of functions that need to be called in a particular order; each function in that order has its *own* order it needs to follow.**

My current code, simplified:

```
async function LastModuleFunction() {
    await FirstModuleFunction(); // Order:1
    await SecondModuleFunction(); // Order: 2
    // ...etc...
    await EighthModuleFunction(); // Order: 8
    setTimeout(GoToNextPage(), 2000); // Order 9
}

function GoToNextPage() {
    // some script irrelevant to this question...
    window.location.href = 'OtherPage.aspx'; // Order: LAST
}
```

*lastModule.js*

```
async function FirstModuleFunction() {
    var obj = { item1: 0, item2: 0, item3: '' }; // you get the idea
    FirstModuleDataSaveProcess();

    async function FirstModuleDataSaveProcess() {
        await FirstModuleDataFunction1(); // Order: 1A
        await FirstModuleDataFunction2(); // Order: 1B
        // I created a shared function for AJAX
        PostDataAjax('AutoSave_ModuleData.asmx/AutoSave_FirstModule', obj, true); // Order: 1C
        // The last parameter is just a boolean to tell the function if it should fire a "Saved!"
        // message (via Toast) upon success.
    }
}
```

*firstModule.js*

```
$('#btnSaveAndFinish').on('click', async function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).html(waitSpinner); // just a bootstrap "please wait" animation here
    LastModuleFunction();
});
```

*moduleNavigation.js*

#### The order MUST go in this pattern: 1A -> 1B -> 1C -> 2A -> 2B -> ... -> LAST

#### Each function in the sequence MUST wait for the previous to complete.

**Boring backstory & context:**
I have an aspx page with multiple UserControl modules (ascx). Which UC's, and how many, depend on the user and the time of day (it's a meeting recorder app that handles 4 different types of meetings each day).

Each time the user navigates to the next module (they come in on a bootstrap carousel), a series of functions prepares the data and sends it to a WebService class (asmx) via AJAX *(see firstModule.js above)*. We tell the user this "auto-saves" the data as they go (which it does).

On the last module, the "next" button is replaced by a "save and finish" button. When clicked, this button goes through EACH of the previous modules *again**,  saves ALL form data to the database through each AJAX function, and THEN `location.href`'s to a different aspx page.

**The user is also able to skip ahead or back to a module, which doesn't trigger an "auto-save," so the app makes extra-sure all data is accounted for.*

**What's actually happening:**
*Most* of the time, this works as intended. The functions fire in order, and the 2-second buffer I give `LastModuleFunction()` is enough time to have the data saved and ready for the next page before it redirects.

...But sometimes, it doesn't/isn't.

**There are two significant tells that indicate something's not right:**

1. In `FirstModuleFunction()`, the WebService called in the AJAX updates a data row that holds the core information for that meeting; the "MeetingCompleted" column in that data row is changed from 'N' to 'Y'. The next page's code, at `Page_Load`, checks if this value is indeed a 'Y'; if not, it redirects back to the original page with a specific query string that tells me that the check failed. So it looks like, in some cases, `FirstModuleFunction()` doesn't complete before the redirect fires.
2. When placing `console.log()` calls before each function in `LastModuleFunction()`, they fire in the correct sequence on the console, each time I tested. However, when I place another `console.log` inside `FirstModuleFunction()`, for example, the console shows a different story:

```
1st module hit
2nd module hit
3rd module hit
function inside 1st module hit   <-- what the...?
4th module hit
[etc.]
```

*console*

I'm now starting to think that simply using `await` when calling `async` functions isn't getting the job done. I can't remember where I read it would be this simple, but it appears I either misunderstood or was misinformed, hm? Apparently I need to use **Promises**...is that correct? Problem is, I could never wrap my head around how to make promises work with this exact sequence structure I need. Can someone help me understand what kind of structure I should be using?

*Note: most of these functions **do not** return any value; they simply act as routines.*

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you're just not *awaiting* all of the `async` operations.  For example, `FirstModuleDataSaveProcess` is `async`, but when you call it you don't `await` it.  The name of `PostDataAjax` also implies that it should be `async`, and it too isn't being `await`ed...

Comment: `async`/`await` is syntactic sugar over promises. They are essentially one and the same, not "different things". If `await` doesn't wait for the function to complete *then there is a problem with the function*. There is no way to fix that with changing over to the promise API for handling the result of the function.

Comment: @David, I think I see...so what you're saying is, if calling a "nested" sequence of functions inside of a "parent" function that's also part of a sequence, I should add `await` to **all** of the child functions? So, for example, the second parent function doesn't wait for a child function of the first parent if there's no `await`?

Comment: @T_O_Massey: You're over-thinking it.  What I'm saying is that if an operation is `async` and you want to wait until it's complete, `await` it.  (If something is asynchronous and doesn't expose itself as an awaitable Promise, that's another issue entirely.)  The nesting is irrelevant.  If you want to `await` the result of an `async` function, `await` it.

Comment: @David, I want to upvote you, but can't just yet. Consider this a +1 "in spirit."

Comment: @T_O_Massey I've got you buddy +1

Comment: This looks like a version of callback hell I haven't seen in a while. Were you overthinking it? (like @David, kind of, suggested?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fix #1: Maintaining Sequence (easier than I thought)

Thanks to Dave's help, I was able to solve *part* of the problem. If a function is part of a sequence of `await` functions, and it has *its own* sequence of child functions that also use `await`, add the `await` to **ALL** of the child functions, else the next "parent" function won't wait for the last child function to finish. It doesn't matter if the function is called last; if `SecondModuleFunction()` is an `await` function, then `PostDataAjax` might end up waiting for it, unless **it** is given an `await`, and your order might be thrown off. When I applied this fix, the console gave me a perfect sequence, every time (1, 1a, 1b, 1c, 2, 2a, 2b, 3, 3a, ...etc.).

```
async function FirstModuleFunction() {
    var obj = { item1: 0, item2: 0, item3: '' }; 
    await FirstModuleDataSaveProcess(); // <--await added here

    async function FirstModuleDataSaveProcess() {
        await FirstModuleDataFunction1(); 
        await FirstModuleDataFunction2(); 
        await PostDataAjax('AutoSave_ModuleData.asmx/AutoSave_FirstModule', obj, true); // <--await added here
    }
}
```

*In other words: when in doubt, **await it.***

### Fix #2: Waiting for AJAX (more tricky)

The bigger problem, I discovered, had to do with that bug I mentioned--where the AJAX wasn't updating the data row server-side, in the background (AJAX -> asmx subroutines) before the page redirected. All of my functions were firing in perfect order, **but without the redirect properly waiting for the AJAX response to the client, none of that mattered.**

Sometimes the `setTimeout` (in my case, 2 seconds) gives it enough time; sometimes it doesn't. I hypothesized that if I added `await` to the `$.ajax` call itself, I was only making the script wait for the **post**, and **not the response from the server**. It turned out I was correct.

**In this case, the solution ended up being a combination of two popular "make the script wait" solutions.** One was, of course, `await`. The other was to add a **callback**:

```
async function PostDataAjax(subdir, dataObj, showSuccess) {

    // Toast customization script went here
    // ...

    // For the callback, we just need SOMETHING. ANYTHING. Don't complicate it.
    await PostData(Toast, simpleCallback); // Of course, I added an await. Just in case. ;)

    async function PostData(Toast, callback) {
        await $.ajax({        // Again, awaiting just in case.
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Ajax/' + subdir,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataObj),
            success: function (result) {
                if (showSuccess === true) {
                    Toast.fire({
                        title: 'Saved!',
                        icon: 'success',
                        timer: 2000
                    });
                }
                callback();  // I'm calling callback both here and in error handling
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                Toast.fire({
                    title: 'Error:',
                    text: 'Trouble saving data. Please contact the Web Team. (' + error + ')',
                    icon: 'error'
                });
                callback();
            }
        });
    }

    function simpleCallback() {    // As I said: don't complicate it. This is as simple as it gets.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Not only did this *work,* but it allowed me to go ahead and remove the 2-second `setTimeout` from the `GoToNextPage()` call. Using `console.log()` markers, I was able to watch the console *take its time* going through each AJAX-related function when I clicked the "finish and save" button. Everything ran in sequence, and did not let the page redirect until it was *done.* Exactly what my goal was.

#### Additional note (2/28/2022):

*To be thorough, I should also point out: obviously, you can (and should) remove `await`s where not necessary, after testing what works best in your script. Be **especially** careful about adding awaits inside of `for` or `each` loops; sure, it might add only a tenth or two of a second to your load time, but if you don't need it there, why keep it?*